# Ant target with unless attribute not considering property value

Tags: ant, ivy, qaf

I am using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) with ant as build script and IVY as dependency management tool. In order to automatic ivy install the build script have following ant target:

```
<target name="download-ivy" unless="skip.download">
    <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}" />
    <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any 
        special installation -->
    <echo message="installing ivy..." />
    <get src="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar" dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true" />
</target>
```

There is build.properties where property `skip.download` provided to download-ivy ON or OFF by providing respective value `true` or `false`.

Now the problem is whatever value i provide for `skip.download` in build.properties it considers it `true`, and always executes the target (downloads ivy).

```
#not working
skip.download=false
```

I referred [IVY + Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/install.html) where it has similar following target with different property name.

```
<target name="download-ivy" unless="offline">

    <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
    <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
    <get src="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.install.version}/ivy-${ivy.install.version}.jar" 
         dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true"/>
</target>
```

I found workaround and as workaround need to remove or comment that property in order to skip download.

> Is there any way so that the property value works fine with unless
>   attribute in target?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following target to install ivy. Note how it uses the available task to determine if ivy is already installed:

```
<available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/>

<target name="install-ivy" description="Install ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>
    <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
</target>
```

**Note:**

- The directory "$HOME/.ant/lib" is one of the standard locations ivy uses to load 3rd party extensions.